# Replacements define

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to get a program that gives all the possible ways of swapping a component to a new one, based on a new component and a list. My goal is to write something simple like:

```
max3 :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a
max3 a b c
      | a > b && a > c = a
      | b > a && b > c = b
      | c > a && c > b = c
      | otherwise = error "."
```

For instance:

```
replacements :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
replacements 'x' "abc" == ["xbc","axc","abx"]
replacements 1 [] == []
```

Comment: Hint: take a look at `inits` and `tails`.

Comment: I cannot understand the question. I get what `replacements` does, but I have no idea what `max3` has to do with it.

Comment: Its just an example, i would like to use case selection (guard).

Comment: Oh I see, so you want to write a function that looks like `max3` and works like `replacements`?

Comment: No, he wants a function that looks like `minimum` but works like `foldr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to write `replacements`:

```hs
replacements :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
replacements _ [] = []
replacements x (y:ys) = (x:ys) : map (y:) (replacements x ys)
```

To understand the recursion, this could be written more verbosely like:

```hs
replacements :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
replacements _ [] = []
replacements x (y:ys) =
  let first = x:ys
      recur = replacements x ys
      rest = map (\x_with_ys -> y:x_with_ys) recur
  in first : rest
```

Evaluating the former of these by hand for `replacements 'x' "abc"`:

```
   replacements 'x' "abc"
~> ('x':"bc") : map ('a':) (replacements 'x' "bc")
~> "xbc" : map ('a':) (('x':"c") : map ('b':) (replacements 'x' "c"))
~> "xbc" : map ('a':) ("xc" : map ('b':) (('x':[]) : map ('c':) (replacements 'x' "")))
~> "xbc" : map ('a':) ("xc" : map ('b':) ("x" : map ('c':) []))
~> "xbc" : map ('a':) ("xc" : map ('b':) ("x" : []))
~> "xbc" : map ('a':) ("xc" : map ('b':) ["x"])
~> "xbc" : map ('a':) ("xc" : ["bx"])
~> "xbc" : map ('a':) ["xc", "bx"]
~> "xbc" : ["axc", "abx"]
~> ["xbc", "axc", "abx"]
```

As Will Ness hinted at, you may want to express this with higher-order functions rather than explicit recursion. To elaborate on Will's hint, try and play around with `inits` and `tails`:

```
λ> import Data.List
λ> inits "abc"
["","a","ab","abc"]
λ> tails "abc"
["abc","bc","c",""]
λ> zip (inits "abc") (tails "abc")
[("","abc"),("a","bc"),("ab","c"),("abc","")]
```

Then look at [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith). (Some coverage in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions).)

---

I also don't know what `max3` has to do with this problem, but another way to write `max3` is:

```hs
max3 :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a
max3 a b c = max a (max b c)
```